# Unit Testing: (JUnit) Fixture

Tags: java

Can somebody help me understand what exactly the Fixture in JUnit and how it works. I googled for the same but failed to understand the same.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: From [github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/test-fixtures): *A test fixture is a fixed state of a set of objects used as a baseline for running tests. The purpose of a test fixture is to ensure that there is a well known and fixed environment in which tests are run so that results are repeatable.*

Comment: There are 4 features of JUnit Test Framework.
Fixtures
Test suites
Test runners
JUnit classes
On some sites definition of fixture given is "Fixtures is a fixed state of a set of objects used as a baseline for running tests. The purpose of a test fixture is to ensure that there is a well-known and fixed environment in which tests are run so that results are repeatable".
Now I am trying to understand what exactly is the Fixture in JUnit Test Framework

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071344/what-are-fixtures-in-programming